# How can I reload Nginx in tomcat web application

Tags: java, nginx

I want to reload nginx when I send a http request to the web application. So In the web application's servlet, I execute the nginx reload command. The Java code is :
"**Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/etc/init.d/nginx reload").waitFor();**". I have tried it but it has no use. But if I login the server as user root, then execute the Java code above, it works!
So I guess the reason is that the tomcat user has no authority to reload nginx. The tomcat process is running as user tomcat6. The nginx master process is running as user root and the nginx worker processes are running as user www-data. How could I solve this problem? Thanks.

My environment :
OS:Ubuntu 10.04
tomcat: 6.0.24
nginx: 1.2.2.
Tomcat and nginx are both installed via the Ubuntu's way "apt-get".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo` command. Also you can grant corresponding authorities to tomcat user. Also you can perform `su` to change user to some that have corresponding authorities and then perform nginx reload. Actually there are a lot of different ways to solve this issue.
I think that it will be better to write and test some script which can reload nginx from tomcat user session and use it for reloading instead of `/etc/init.d/nginx reload` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me how can I grant corresponding authorities to tomcat user and what authorities should I grant to tomcat user? I'm not very familiar with Linux, only a little:)

Comment: First of all, you can execute `ls -la | grep nginx` command to determine wich user and group owns nginx. In my case all daemons has root group and root user as their owners. So, I can add new group responsible for nginx management using command `sudo groupadd nginx_admin`. Then I can set owner group of nginx to nginx_admin group using command `sudo chown root:nginx_admin /etc/init.d/nginx`. Notice, that I used root as owner user of the nginx, because I don't want to change it. Then you can finally add tomcat user to nginx_admin group using `sudo usermod -a -G nginx_admin tomcat`.